# Open a link using the button and textfield

Tags: swift, xcode

Can I open a link using the button and textfield on which the link is listed on another page within the app itself and not with Safari?

I'm using Swift 4

[image]

Comment: It certainly is possible, but you should show what you have tried so far.  I recommend you do some research into `URLs`, passing `Data` with `Segues`, and `WKWebView`

Comment: It is possible. Take text from text field and convert it to URL then create `SFSafariViewController` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) or `WKWebView` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) using that URL, you can display those controllers inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use WKWebView to open the link on Button action using this 
Import WebKit
import WebKit

> In your FirstViewController pass the URL while pushing to
>   SecondViewController

**FirstViewController**

```
if let secondVC = (UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVCID") {
    secondVC.url = textFiled.text // OR send the URL you want to send
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
```

**In SecondViewController**

```
Import Webkit
```

declare the delegate

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate  {
```

> declare the URL var so that u cab access it n FirstVC

```
var url: String?
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


In ViewDidLoad Of SecondVC

let webUrl = NSURL(string: url!)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: webUrl)

// load request in webview.
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

and Implement all delegate methods of WKWebview

```
//MARK:- WKNavigationDelegate

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Strat to load")
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to open webview in destination view controller and send url string from first view controller to destination like below:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {

        if let mainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as? DestinationViewController {
            mainVC.urlStr = textField.text
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: true)

        }
    }
}
```

> Destination View controller:

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    var urlStr: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        if let urlString = urlStr, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}
```